# Como passar uma lista grande de objetos para API em C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Estou passando uma lista de objetos para a minha API em C#. Quando o tamanho da lista é menor, tudo ocorre como deveria ocorrer. Quando a lista é um pouco maior a lista chega vazia em minha API.

Quando a lista é menor obtenho o resultado esperado:

[image: Com uma lista menor dá tudo certo]

No entanto quando mando essa lista:

[image: Array mandado]

Obtenho esse resultado:

[image: Lista de Objetos vazia]

Alguém poderia me explicar o porque e como resolver esse problema?

Comment: sua API está sendo publicada pelo IIS?

Comment: Sim, está sendo executada pelo IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode modificar o elemento [`httpRuntime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx) no arquivo *web.config* adicionando o seguinte atributo. Isso deve resolver o problema do objeto ter valor nulo ao executar o POST.

```
// limite para o buffer de fluxo de entrada, em kilobytes
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```

---

Porém, pode ser que você tenha problemas com a [filtragem de requisição](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/) introduzida na versão 7.0 do IIS. Mais especificamente (tradução minha):

> Quando a filtragem de requisição bloqueia uma solicitação HTTP, o IIS
>   7 retornará um erro HTTP 404 ao cliente e registrará o status HTTP com
>   um *substatus* único que identifica o motivo pelo qual a solicitação
>   foi negada.

```
+----------------+------------------------------+
| HTTP Substatus |         Descrição            |
+----------------+------------------------------+
|          404.5 | Sequência URL Negada         |
|          404.6 | Verbo Negado                 |
|          404.7 | Extensão de arquivo Negada   |
|          ...   |                              |
```

Para resolver essa limitação, você pode modificar o elemento `<requestLimits>` dentro do arquivo *web.config*

```
// limita o POST para 10MB, query string para 256 chars, url para 1024 chars
<requestLimits maxQueryString="256" maxUrl="1024" maxAllowedContentLength="102400000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente enviar dessa forma:

```
public JsonResult PdfSellout(List<SellOut> sellout)
{
        var lista = buscarLista();
        var jsonResult = Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
}
```

Edit:
O método acima é para resposta, para envio de arquivos use o seguinte:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;

var content = new CompressedContent(new StreamContent(new FileStream("c:\\big-json-file.json",FileMode.Open)),"UTF8");

var response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://example.org/", content).Result;
```

para uma string grande use esse [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/734080/How-to-Pass-a-Large-String-to-a-Web-API-Method-A)

para uma lista de objetos, use esse [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1180464/Large-JSON-Array-Streaming-in-ASP-NET-Web-API)